# Can you add privilege level command to allow a certain user to add new users for an ASA?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I thought I could get this done by doing the following:

```
privilege cmd level 6 mode exec command user
```

But under a user with that priv level the user can only do the following

```
user newuser
```

They can't assign a password and priv level.

Maybe there is a better / another way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the reason for wanting this? TACACS+ or RADIUS may be better options.

Comment: I was trying to think of the fastest way to give a client the ability to do this (to manage vpn users). I found out we have enough time to implement a RADIUS service so that will be the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In exec mode, `user` expands to `user-alert`; this isn't what you want.

You're probably looking for something more along these lines:

```
privilege cmd level 6 mode configure command username
```

And then possibly some allowances for config-username mode:

```
privilege cmd level 6 mode username command service-type
privilege cmd level 6 mode username command group-lock
...
```

But that's worthless as anything other than a thought exercise.  If I'm a restricted level 6 user, and I'm allowed to run the `username` command in configure mode, then I can create myself a level 15 user; it's just a waste of effort to put a completely ineffective restriction in place.  Adam's exactly right, TACACS+ should be used for this.

Comment: Agh well that explains it! Good to know at least.